# Opencart 3.0.3.2 register/login urls are not seo friendly

Tags: .htaccess, url, opencart-3

I have created a opencart store using 3.0.3.2 version and enabled the seo url option from the admin panel and changed .htaccess.txt into .htaccess

The product and category url's are seo friendly. But register/login url's are not making as seo friendly. I have added the below settings into the seo url section from admin panel.

```
login
query : account/login
keyword : login
store : default
language : English

Register
query : account/login
keyword : login
store : default
language : English
```

What could be issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I found this one if this module still help https://webocreation.com/blog/remove-route-in-opencart-for-contact-home-and-other/

Comment: I think this is nothing to do with the modules. There will be some tricky ways to resolve this issue. I am trying to find it out.